# Filepicker.io upload fails with mobile safari full-screen

Tags: filepicker.io

Filepicker.io works fine if I use my single-page angular.js app using a desktop, ipad, or iphone directly from mobile safari. But if I add my website to the iphone homescreen, and run the app using:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Then the app fails immediately upon choice of picture when selecting from camera. It displays a red bar error, something to the effect of "end results to the screen failed. Please close this window and try again..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version: Use the {container} option to open filepicker.io into an iframe in your page in this case.

More full explanation:
The default mobile behavior is to open in a new window, and the current iOS model will spawn a new safari instance from homescreen apps off window.open(). When Filepicker.io then sends the data back to the calling app, the Safari sandboxing prevents the data from being transmitted, causing the error seen.

To fix this behavior, you can force Filepicker.io open in an iframe in the page by using the {container} property.

Comment: Should this still work? I was seeing the same problem as the original poster, and wasn't able to resolve it with this solution. Even if Filepicker.io opens on the page, it spawns a new safari instance to get the permissions. It could be I'm not doing it right - is there more information about how to set this up somewhere?